Reference request: monoidal stacks, $2$-stacks, etc
Through my research I've been exposed to notions such as $2$-stacks, gr-stacks, monoidal stacks, torsors under stacks, etc., mainly in the setting of abstract sites or sites over a scheme. I'm not that comfortable working with and thinking about such objects, so I'd like to know if there is a reference that treats all (or many) of these notions in a unified way, preferably without reference to $\infty$-categories. I'd be very happy with an informal introduction too. Thank you!

I'd try Toën's notes here: https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0604504. All I did was look up things that cite Breen's original articles on this stuff on Google Scholar, FWIW; this isn't a field with a particularly vast literature. There's lots of stuff by Baez from the '90s and '00s that's guaranteed to be clear and inspiring, though possibly more aimed at mathematical physics than you want.
